# I need to get popup to change registry value when I do PC shutdown

Tags: windows-registry

I am trying to get popup to ask me on machine shutdown, do I want to change autologin registry change yes to change value 1 and no to change value 0. VB script is doing this job but when I run file on task scheduler or by local group policy, popup is not appearing. machine goes to shutdown/restart.

Script:

```
Set Shell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Dim WshShell

Answer = MsgBox("Do You Want To" & vbNewLine & "change reg value on Your Computer?",vbYesNo,"Change:")
If Answer = vbYes Then
    Set WshShell=WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    WshShell.RegWrite "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\" _
        & "CurrentVersion\Winlogon\AutoAdminLogon", "1", "REG_SZ"
    Set WshShell=Nothing
    Ending = 1
ElseIf Answer = vbNo Then
    Set WshShell=WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    WshShell.RegWrite "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\" _
        & "CurrentVersion\Winlogon\AutoAdminLogon", "0", "REG_SZ"
    Set WshShell=Nothing
    If Stopping = vbYes Then
        WScript.Quit 0
    End If
End If
```

Comment: After you've clicked shutdown is simply far too late to do anything that needs user intervention, at that point the system is closing things down and killing applications and, depending on what user your task is running as, scripts run from Task Scheduler cannot display GUI prompts. You would be better off simplifying your script to check the presence of some file you create or delete before shutdown. Alternatively simply add the shutdown command into your script, run it manually to do the setup and shutdown and avoid the Start menu shutdown button entirely. Johns answer pretty much sums it up

Answer (score 2):

Once shutdown has initiated, you can’t pause it to deal with an issue.

Create a batch file to prompt for the issue, deal with the issue, come back to the batch file via an exit code, and then issue shutdown /s

Another way (better for me) is to separate the two things: deal with your issue and then shut down separately.

Comment: many thanks for your input. separately every thing working fine. objective is to run specific script when shutdown button pressed to dictate what machine, what setting should be in registry after reboot.

Comment: You need a person or a batch process set the registry before pressing the the shut down buttons as it is too later after the button is pressed.

Answer (score 0):

At the end of your script; add
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/psshutdown